# Как задать размер массиву при конструировании объекта, размер известен и является constexpr

Tags: c++

Допустим есть класс:

```
class A{
public:
    constexpr A(size_t sz):size{sz}{}
private:
    constexpr size_t size;
    int mass[size];
};

constexpr size_t mass_size{10};
A a{mass_size};
```

массив нужно создать именно на стеке

Comment: конструктор является константным выражением?...

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. "Нужно создать массив на стеке" - это понятно. Но к чему здесь этот класс и какое он имеет отношение к вопросу?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

К сожалению, только с использованием шаблонов. Это легко:

```
template <size_t Size>
class A {

private:
    int mass[Size];
};

constexpr size_t mass_size{10};
A<mass_size> a;
```

---

Почему нельзя Вашим способом? Это тоже легко объяснить. Компилятор видит `A a{ ... };`, с его точки зрения это объект типа `A`. Но возникает вопрос - а какой размер у этого объекта? В вашем случае `sizeof(A) == mass_size * sizeof(int)`. Уже видите проблему? Любые `pure-constexpr` аргументы, если бы они существовали, меняли бы описание класса, что на самом деле и происходит в случае шаблонов. Поэтому даже если бы Ваш вариант каким-либо образом работал, то конструкции `A{10}` и `A{20}` имели бы разный тип. Так что используйте шаблонный класс =)

Comment: обьявить можно просто A<10> a;   без лишных константных выражений

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, можно, но `constexpr` подчеркивает, что выражение может быть не просто числовой константой, а результатом вычисляемого во время компиляции выражения

Answer (score 0):

Можно в классе хранить указатель или умный указатель, но массив хранить можно только с определенным размером для каждого типа. Поэтому ваш класс может быть или шаблонным(чтобы генерировался массив при каждом инстанцировании) или, например так:

```
class A{
public:
    A(size_t sz)
    {
        mass = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[sz]);
    }
    // получить указатель на массив
    int* get_array() const { return mass.get(); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> mass;
};
```

Comment: А разве `std::unique_ptr<int>` не вызовет в деструкторе `delete` (вместо `delete []`) на вашем указателе, тем самым создавая неопределенное поведение? Имхо, стоит заменить его на `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`. (Либо поставить кастомный deleter, но это не особо красиво.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , да, там нужно добавлять [],  чтобы корректно уничтожать массив

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, 
> Либо поставить кастомный deleter, но это не особо красиво
А почему не красиво? Просто интересно :)

Comment: @isnullxbh Писать больше. Зачем, если достаточно дописать два символа. Да и к тому же, `unique_ptr<int[]>` имеет удобный перегруженный `operator[]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, понял, спасибо.